# PowerShell AST FindAll method take a scriptblock with $args[0]

Tags: powershell, abstract-syntax-tree

I have been working with the PowerShell AST to create some custom rules for PSScriptAnalyzer.

In a lot of the example code for AST, there is one line that I don't understand. Here is an example.

First parse a file, in this case, the current open file in the ISE.

```
$AbstractSyntaxTree = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]:: 
                  ParseInput($psISE.CurrentFile.Editor.Text, [ref]$null, [ref]$null)
```

This makes sense so far. Let's say that we want to look for all the ParameterAst objects. The code that I have seen to do this is below.

```
$params = $AbstractSyntaxTree.FindAll({$args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.ParameterAst]}, $true)
```

This line of code is calling `FindAll` and passing in a scriptblock, that seems to be acting as a filter, so that only ParameterAst objects are returned.

What I don't understand here is how `$args[0]` fits into this call. How are any parameters actually getting passed into the scriptblock when the `FindAll` method is invoked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FindAll` method has following signature (from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj136376%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```cs
public IEnumerable<Ast> FindAll (
    Func<Ast,bool> predicate,
    bool searchNestedScriptBlocks
)
```

So first argument is a delegate that takes [Ast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.language.ast%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as input, and returns bool. 
In Powershell you can create such delegate like that:

```bsh
$delegate = { param($ast) $ast -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.ParameterAst] }
```

Or without declaring parameter:

```bsh
$delegate = { $args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.ParameterAst] }
```

`FindAll` method will then do something like that (pseudocode):

```bsh
foreach ($node in $allNodes) {
    $shouldAdd = & $delegate $node  <-- this is how $node gets passed to your delegate
    if ($shouldAdd) {
       <add the node to the output list>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of the scriptblock as an anonymous callback function.

It's really the same thing that happens when you use `Where-Object { $someCondition }`.

[`.FindAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj136376(v=vs.85).aspx) finds all the (things) and for each one it calls the function you provided it. It's apparently expecting a `[bool]` result, and returning the objects that satisfied the conditions present in the callback.

In a function or script or scriptblock in powershell, you can have named parameters that are explicitly defined, or you can [reference parameters without declaring them using the `$args` array](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx), which is what's happening here.

Using a scriptblock as a callback is similar to using it for an event:

> $Args
>
> ```
>    Contains an array of the undeclared parameters and/or parameter
>    values that are passed to a function, script, or script block.
>    When you create a function, you can declare the parameters by using the
>    param keyword or by adding a comma-separated list of parameters in
>    parentheses after the function name.
>
>    In an event action, the $Args variable contains objects that represent
>    the event arguments of the event that is being processed.
> ```